# K&R exercise 1-24

Tags: c

> Exercise 1-24. Write a program to check a C program for rudimentary
> syntax errors like unmatched parentheses, brackets and braces. Don't
> forget about quotes, both single and double, escape sequences, and
> comments. (This program is hard if you do it in full generality.)

This is the code I wrote for the program(It's not complete yet, I'll work on it more later on):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define YES 1
#define NO 0

int a = 0;

void push(int stack[], int c);
void pull(int stack[]);
int check(int stack[], int c);

int main()
{
    int stack[1000], c, keep = 1;

    extern int a;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && keep == YES)
    {
        if (c == '[' || c == '(' || c == '{')
            push(stack, c);

        else if (c == ']' || c == ')' || c == '}')
            keep = check(stack, c);

    }

    return 0;
}

void push(int stack[], int c)
{
    int i;

    for (i = a; i; --i)
        stack[i+1] = stack[i];

    ++a;

    stack[0] = c;
}

void pull(int stack[])
{
    int i;

    --a;

    for (i = 0; i < a; ++i)
        stack[i] = stack[i+1];

    stack[a] = '\0';
}

int check(int stack[], int c)
{
    if ((c == ']' && stack[0] == '[') || (c == ')' && stack[0] == '(') || (c == '}' && stack[0] == '{'))
    {
        pull(stack);
        return YES;
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Mismatched character: '%c'\n", c);
        return NO;
    }
}
```

when I give it an output like `{}` or `(   ) () {} []` it works but with something like `(())` it gives me this output:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you "push" on to the end? This looks like it shuffles things around a ton, which defeats the point of a stack.

Comment: Instead of making your own C dialect with `YES` and `NO`, why not just use C as intended with zero meaning false, non-zero (default `1`) meaning true?

Comment: I advise writing a stack library, including tests to make sure your stack library works. Then use that (tested and verified) library in this parentheses matching code. As-is, it's hard to suss out whether the error is in your stack implementation or your matching implementation. If you're working through K&R exercises, you're bound to reuse that library.

Comment: It's also worth noting that you push into your stack the opening character, but then are left with a really obnoxious checker function that has to invert. Why not push *the closing character you're expecting* which massively simplifies that, at near zero additional cost on the push side. Using a `switch` there is probably a good idea.

Comment: Your error reporting could be better. Instead of just "Mismatched character", consider also reporting the position of the mismatch.

Comment: Consider renaming `a` to `stack_size` or similar. Good variable names help people troubleshooting your code (which is sometimes YOU)

Comment: Do you know how to use your debugger? Learn how to use your debugger. Right now. You shouldn't have to keep 100 things in your short term memory to understand why a program is failing. You should be able to use your modern tools to inspect the variables in memory at a specific failure point.

Comment: `extern` is for variables that are being shared between compilation units. Use a global variable for variables that are shared only between functions in the same compilation unit. And it makes no sense for `a` to be shared but `stack` is local. Either they're both parameters to the function or neither.

Comment: @Barmar: What? C does not have a global scope. If it did, a global scope is one that is visible throughout the entire program, meaning, if you declared it in one source file, it would be visible in all source files. Do you mean `static` or internal linkage?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good point, I meant file scope, which is declared with `static` outside the function.

Comment: @Barmar according to the book the functions would change the original rather than a copy of it unlike other variables, that's why I made a extern and stak local

Comment: Tip: Do the last part first; ie: develop a method to **not** find target characters (braces/brackets) that are inside single or double quotes or comments (both "/* */" and "//".) Otherwise, there will be a plethora of _flags_ to set/test/clear and the logic will become impenetrable... Perhaps load the entire (smallish) file into a buffer and perform a few _passes_ over it _neutralising_ problematic situations, then set about analysing the sequence of open/close braces & brackets... How would your current program react (when working) analysing its own source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `push` routine is broken. The loop `for (i = a; i; --i)` never executes the body when `i` is zero, so it never executes `stack[1] = stack[0]`. You need the test to be `i >= 0`. (However, there is a better way to implement a stack without moving all the elements every time there is a push or pop. Also, we call removing an item from the top of a stack a “pop,” not a “pull.”)